# A collection of the fragments of Eudemus of Rhodes?

Tags: reference-request, antiquity, greek-mathematics

I am looking for a complete collection of fragments of [Eudemus of Rhodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudemus_of_Rhodes). He is considered to be the first historian of science. His fragments have given us a glimpse of how Greek mathematics developed through the earliest Greek philosophers.

Are the fragments of Eudemus available online in Ancient Greek or English?

---

**Potential Candidates:**

- *Edemas von Rhodos*, by F. Wehrli (1955) gathered 90 fragments of Eudemus for *Die Schule des Aristoteles vol. VIII*
- *Eudemus of Rhodes* by István Bodnár, William Fortenbaugh (2002) is a complete collection of the fragments and testimonia of Eudemus.

Comment: Inter-library loan can get you the actual books, so why not go that route?

Comment: @JonCuster I will definitely purchase the physical copies of the books, however I do not want to type all of the Ancient Greek by hand. Do you think the PDFs available through ILL?

Comment: I'm sure that you are already aware of this, but no original writings of Eudemus exist.  The term *fragments* is used to describe direct quotes from later commentators (*testimonia* refers to paraphrasing by later commentators).  Even direct quotes may not be accurate.

Comment: @nwr Thanks for pointing that out, I made a mistake in my question then. I'll fix that.

Comment: Based on the [abstract and downloadable preview PDF](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/edit/10.4324/9781351324489/eudemus-rhodes-william-fortenbaugh), the book edited by Bodnár & Fortenbaugh is a collection of essays on Eudemus, not a collection of fragments and testimonia. The abstract also calls the book "a necessary complement to Wehrli's edition of Eudemus' fragments".

Comment: Wehrli's collection of fragments is [available](https://archive.org/details/trent_0116403085024) for borrowing from the Internet Archive. Contains 151 fragments in the original Greek plus commentary in German, but one cannot copy and paste, and (based on a couple of attempts) text searching in Greek seems not to work.

Comment: @Senex Fantastic, thank you! This works. It will be easy to find where each  reference is located online (i.e. fragment 1 is located in Simplicius' commentary on Aristotle's Physics)